# Python Workflow Frameworks/Libraries

Tags: python, workflow, hbase, key-value-store

I am trying to create workflow engine running on top of key value store, hbase. Can you guide me if there exists a strong python framework/library without a persistence layer (I need to implement my own persistence layer).

Answer (score 1):

Hello again Ankit (we met on the ruote mailing list),

I found this library the other day:

https://github.com/romanchyla/workflow

There is no mention about persistence, perhaps it's "in-memory" or it uses "pickles".

It seems to be BSD licensed (to the CERN).

Comment: Thanks, I ended up creating a simple workflow execution engine. Although, this seems to be interesting as per the description.